# Conditional expectation of random variable given minimal sigma-algebra generators

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I am trying to understand better the definition of conditional expectation, for that I want to prove the following:

Let $X$ be a random variable in the probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\Sigma$ and let $\mathcal{P}$ be a partition of $\Omega$ such that $\mathcal{P}$ are the minimal generators of $\mathcal{F}$, i.e. $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(\mathcal{P})$.

I want to show that:
$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) = \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}(X \mid \mathcal{P})$$

Comment: By definition: $\mathbb{E}_P(X\mid \mathcal{P}) = \mathbb{E}_P(X\mid \sigma(\mathcal{P})) = \mathbb{E}_P(X\mid \mathcal{F})$. Actually the way conditional expectation is defined, the only way of interpreting the second argument in $\mathbb{E}_P(X\mid *)$ is as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by it. (i.e. $\sigma(*)$).

Comment: Why do you interpret the second argument in $\mathbb{E}_P(X\mid *)$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by it? This should be my question

Comment: If you start from the [most general definition of conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra), you define $\mathbb{E}_P(X\mid \mathcal{F})$ **only** for sub $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}$ of $\Sigma$. Hence the only interpretation of $*$ in $\mathbb{E}_P(X\mid *)$ has to be $\sigma(*)$.

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}(X|\mathcal P)$?

Comment: I'm using the definition given by Williams - "Probability with Martingales", i.e., $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}(X|\mathcal F)$ is the random variable $Y$ that is $\mathcal F$-measurable and satisfies that $\int_A Y d\mathbb P = \int_A X d\mathbb P, \forall A \in \mathcal F$. But for $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}(X|\mathcal P)$ I don't have any definition since$\mathcal P$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: So what is the standard definition of $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}(X|\mathcal P)$?

Comment: I am not sure. I imagine that $E(X|\mathcal P)$ is defined like this. Given $\omega\in \Omega$, let $\mathcal P(\omega)$ be the part of $\mathcal P$ containing $\omega$. Then $E(X|\mathcal P)=E(X\cdot {\bf 1}(\mathcal P(\omega)))/\mathbb P(\mathcal P(\omega)).$ (Also, if you want me to be notified of your comment, you need to include `@MikeEarnest` in your comment).